# Is there a way to resize margins when exporting PDF in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, latex, org-export, pdf

I want to export my `org` document as a PDF, but its margins are way too big. I would like to re-size them as I wish. I am using

```
#+LaTeX_CLASS: report
```

I do not know if there is a way. Any help?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The simplest way to tweak the formatting of a LaTeX export is by using the `geometry` package. Try something like this:

`#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}`

Answer (score 18):

Another way to achieve the same effect more permanently is to modify `org-latex-packages-alist` to add the `geometry` package, as follows:

```
(setq org-latex-packages-alist '(("margin=2cm" "geometry" nil)))
```

Comment: Does this overwrite an existing list, append to it, or is the default empty anyway?

Comment: @AstroFloyd in my environment, `org-latex-packages-alist` is empty by default.

Comment: One down-side of such modifications could be creating problems for beamer class exporting (geometry package is not compatible with beamer).